# Using a String Array in an IN statement

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a column in database that stores an array of numbers in a nvarchar string and the values look like this
`"1,5,67,122"`

Now, I'd like to use that column value in a query that utilizes IN statement

However, if I have something like

```
WHERE columnID IN (@varsArray);
```

it doesn't work as it sees @varsArray as a string and can't compare it to `columnID` which is of INT type.

how can I convert that variable to something that could be used with a IN statement?

Comment: DON'T DO THAT! CSV data in columns is **EVIL!**

Comment: that is an existing design that can't be changed at the moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need dynamic SQL for that.

```
exec('select * from your_table where columnID in (' + @varsArray + ')')
```

#### And BTW it is bad DB design to store more than 1 value in a column!

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you can parse your variable with finding a split user defined function on the internet and enter each number into a temp table and then join the temp table

but the person who answered above is correct this is bad database design

create a table so you can join it based on some id, and all the answers will be in a table (temporary or not)

Answer (score 0):

One other option is to use a User Defined Table-Valued function that takes a delimited string as input and generates a table with one row per value as its output (see [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns)), and then, using [Cross Apply](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/796821b0-ba48-49b4-ba42-1783061d8c41/cross-apply-in-sqlserver?forum=transactsql), join the table itself to the output of that UDF.

These techniques are useful to have in your trick-bag anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we're forced to work against bad data designs sometimes...

I've seen this done by building and calling a SQL function that splits out the numbers and returns them in a table. Then you could run your columnID against that temp table to see if it exists.